# How to use self signed certificate with private key in lib curl to download file from windows azure blob storage

Tags: c++, libcurl, azure-storage

I am  using libcurl to download blob from windows azure which made as public and succesfully able to download with http site. But if the azure blob storage make as private with self signed certificate and privte key then file download fails with message "The specified resource does not exist"

Code is as below

```
CURL *curl; 
    FILE *fp; 
    CURLcode res; 
    bool success = true;
    string CloudContainerPath = "https://MyTest.blob.core.windows.net/Mytest/";
    string path = CloudContainerPath+fileNameJsonVal.asCString();
    char *url = &path[0];  
    char *outfilename = (char *)fileNameJsonVal.asCString(); 
    char                errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    int length = 0;
    errbuf[0] = '\0';

static const char *pCACertFile = "D:\\LibCURL\\cacert.pem";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url); 
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
                * set the file with the certs vaildating the server */ 
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH,pCACertFile);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_CAINFO,pCACertFile);


                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data); 
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp); 


res = curl_easy_perform(curl); 
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
                fclose(
```

fp);

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure storage doesn't use certificate-based authentication. It uses shared keys with HMAC signatures. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx.

Comment: Can anyone help me out to put authentication string here?